# ошибка cs1061 в visual studio

Tags: c#

При создании приложения, появилась ошибка cs1061. Вот сам код:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                {
                    sw.Write(fastColoredTextBox1.Text); // ругается на Text
                }
            }
        }
```

вот описание ошибки:
[image: описание]

Comment: Что такое `fastColoredTextBox1`? Покажите как определяете его. Это что, Winforms? Поставьте метку.

Comment: fastColoredTextBox1 сам не знаю что. Взял этот код с ютуба. Я делаю инжектор для игры.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если вы не понимаете основы основ языка, программирования, то о каком инженторе может идти речь? Ведь это весьма серьезная тема. У вас на форме должен быть `TextBox` элемент, который имеет название `fastColoredTextBox1`, вот к нему идет обращение, конкретно по ошибке, у вас есть скорей всего гдет еще `fastColoredTextBox1`, который является `object` типом, из него пытается найти свойство и не находит. Советую подучить основы перед тем, как лезть в такие дебри, утоните очень быстро и забросите...

Comment: Ошибка значит, что у `fastColoredTextBox1` нет свойства `Text`, больше из этого кода и текста ошибки понять ничего нельзя.